# about Sinatra on multiple Resources

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Sorry to ask such a simple question but I didn't see any possible answer in internet.

I just wondering in Sinatra, can I write something like:

```
get '/users/:user_id/posts/:id' do
  xxx
end
```

just like rails? cause when I write this on my rb file, sinatra keep telling me it didn't know this ditty.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (horrible) example from one of our legacy systems.

```
get '/is_type/:type/id/:id' do
   store.valid_for_type?(params)
end
```

Multiple placeholders in a route is totally fine in Sinatra.  It sounds like your config.ru is wrong, you're issuing a POST, or you're calling the wrong endpoint entirely.  Can you update your post with an example of the request you are issuing?

Comment: sorry about that, I made a stupid mistake that I forgot to add / infront of users ..... : (